# Windows Phone Application page background image size

Tags: windows-phone, background-image

I am new to windows phone development. I want to design a background image for the page. I am just using a regular page **not** the panarama view.  What size should I make the background image to fit the different screen resolutions will it scale it down if the phone screen size is smaller?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The different resolutions are 1280x768, 1280x720, or 800x480. If you, say, used a 1280x768 image, the behavior on the other aspect ratio (1280x720), or if you used an aspect ratio that doesn't match the screen, depends on what you enter as the image's Stretch property.

See this for the different stretch options: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch(v=vs.95).aspx